# Python 3 dictionary d.items(), d.keys()

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm kind of confused on `d.items()` and `d.keys()`. My textbook said that they return view objects that are tuples but they can be changed? For instance, my code is this

```
d = {"Bob":27, "Frank":75}

for key, value in d.items():
    if d[key] == 27:
        d[key] = 20
        print(d)
```

It prints out 20 instead of 27.

Comment: Because you changed it....

Comment: Their point is that how can it be changed if it returns tuples since tuples items can't be changed @ᴡʜᴀᴄᴋᴀᴍᴀᴅᴏᴏᴅʟᴇ3000

Answer (score 2):

What your textbook means is that if the keys of the dictionary change, then so will the [view](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dictionary-view-objects).

```
d = {1: 1}

keys = d.keys() # dict_keys([1])

d[2] = 2

keys # dict_keys([1, 2])
```

The same happens for items.

```
d = {1: 1}

items = d.items() # dict_items([(1, 1)])

d[2] = 2

keys # dict_keys([(1, 1), (2, 2)])
```

Also, they are not tuples, they have their own class.

```
isinstance(d.keys(), tuple) # False

type(d.keys()) # <class 'dict_keys'>

type(d.items()) # <class 'dict_items'>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
a = {
    'a': 'aa',
    'b': 'bb',
    'c': 'cc'
}

for k,v in a.items(): # does't change anything.
    k = 'c' # k is the first item of the tuples in the dict_items object

for k in a.keys(): # doesn't change anything.
    k = 'd' # k is the first item of the tuples in the dict_keys object

for k,v in a.items():
    # you are using __setitem__ method of the dictionary with the first item of the tuple
    # so you are not actually changing the tuple
    # you are just using the tuple to index the dictionary
    a[k] = v + '!!!' # you find the value of the given key, and added a string to it 

print(a.items()) # will print a dict_items object containing key,value tuples of the dictionary
```

-~-~-~-~-~-

```
for a in a.items(): # does't change anything
    print(isinstance(a,tuple))
```

The above code vill give you all True because every item in the dict_items object is indeed a tuple. `a.items()` doesn't return tuples yet returns an object which holds tuples.

Comment: `keys` and `items` do not return tuples, they are their own type subclassed from the base type of Python.

Comment: They don't. They return objects which holds tuples. Let me edit my answer so you can see it better. I even said they are the tuples inside the `dict_keys` object, I'm not sure why you are confused.

Comment: This is kind of technical, and you can think of it as a tuple, but it does not have an internal tuple. It's really a memory view at the C code level

Comment: @Olivier, I believe you. But if you cycled through `for i in a.items()`, would `i` act in all ways like you would expect a tuple to act, e.g. immutable, and so the only difference is the way it is held in memory?

Comment: You are almost correct if you loop, because you don't have access to the object `a.items()` returned. but the whole point is that if you do `a[k] = v + '!!!'`, yes the object returned by `a.items()` actually changed.

Comment: @Olivier They are documented as tuples, their isinstance shows that they are tuples, their types are tuples. As far as python cares; they are tuples.

Comment: Wrong: `isinstance(d.keys(), tuple) # False` see my answer

Comment: I said this; I even edited my answer. d.keys() is not a tuple, datas are holded in it, `for x in d.items()` every x is a tuple.

Comment: We are getting too deep in this argument for the comment section. Especially for a detail that technical.

Comment: I haven't edited anything; I just added the last part so you can see that they are indeed tuples.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166161/discussion-between-olivier-and-isik-kaplan).